# RoR: attr_encrypted assignment doesn't get written?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, encryption

I'm using `attr_encrypted` (v 1.2.0) in RoR 3.0.5 to encrypt credentials that I don't want appearing as plain text in my db.  When I update the encrypted field, it appears that it's not getting saved into the db.

My model is essentially:

```
class Service << ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_encrypted :credentials_aux, :key => KEY, :attribute => 'encrypted_credentials', :encode => true, :marshal => true

  def credentials
    credentials_aux
  end

  def credentials=(c)
    h = {}.update(c)  # coerce HashWithIndifferentAccess to a vanilla hash
    credentials_aux = h
  end

  ...
end
```

(Note that the 'credentials=' method exists simply to coerce a Rails-generated HashWithIndifferentAccess into a vanilla hash.  It also gives me a place to interpose debugging printout to verify my data.)

But when I try updating credentials via the console, it doesn't take:

```
>> s = Service.find(19)
=> #<Service id: 19, encrypted_credentials: "10VfHU7IkdrFb4Q6Hj18YtY81rbRp3sIuoVUl8CHNj88cq1XFo2...",>
>> s.credentials
=> {"user_id"=>"fred.flintstone", "password"=>"supersecret"}
>> s.credentials = {"user_id" => "barney.rubble", "password" => "notsosecret"}
=> {"user_id" => "barney.rubble", "password" => "notsosecret"}
>> s.credentials
=> {"user_id"=>"fred.flintstone", "password"=>"supersecret"}
```

Why didn't `s.credentials` get updated to the new value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're just setting a local variable called "credentials_aux" in your "credentials=" method, try explicitly using "self"

```
def credentials=(c)
  h = {}.update(c)  # coerce HashWithIndifferentAccess to a vanilla hash
  self.credentials_aux = h
end
```

I'm actually the maintainer of that project, so if the fix above doesn't work then I'll open up a new ticket for this.

Comment: You don't get any better service than this.

Comment: worked like a champ - many thanks for the prompt reply (and the awesome gem).  @brett: word!

Comment: by the way, is my approach to casting HashWithIndifferentAccess to a regular hash reasonable?  Or is there some simpler way to do that?

Comment: @fearless_fool You could try using [HashWithIndifferentAccess#to_hash](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html#M000028)